# Dynamic Allocation of Memory in C++

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, allocation

I'm trying to figure out dynamic allocation in c++ but i encountered a problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

float *alocareV(int n)
{
    float *v;
    v = (float *)malloc(n*sizeof(float));
    return v;
}

float **alocareM(int m, int p)
{
    float **a;
    int i;
    a = (float **)malloc(m*sizeof(float));
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        *(a + i) = (float *)malloc(p*sizeof(float));
    return a;
}

void dezalocareM(float **a ,int p)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
        free (*(a + i));
}

void citireV(float *v, int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("v[%d]= ", i);
        scanf_s("%f", *(v + i));
    }
}

void citireM(float **a, int m, int p)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m;i++)
    for (j = 0; j < p; j++)
    {
        printf("a[%d][%d]= ", i, j);
        scanf_s("%f", *( *(a + i) + j ) );
    }
}

void main()
{
    float *v=0, **a=0;
    int n, m, p;
    int i, j;

    printf("n este egal cu ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    printf("m este egal cu ");
    scanf_s("%d", &m);
    printf("p este egal cu ");
    scanf_s("%d", &p);

    alocareV(n);
    alocareM(m, p);

    citireV(v, n);
    citireM(a, m, p);

    free(v);
    dezalocareM(a, p);

}
```

Firstly i had to initialize *v=0 and **a=0 in main because i got an error telling me "uninitialized local variable used". If i didn't use subprograms that error wouldn't appear.
Secondly after entering the 3 variables (n, m, p) i get a stopped working box with the problems detalis being:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: AlocareDinamica.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    54f1d7f9
  Fault Module Name:    AlocareDinamica.exe
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   54f1d7f9
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00014059
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.768.100
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 5861
  Additional Information 2: 5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
  Additional Information 3: a10f
  Additional Information 4: a10ff7d2bb2516fdc753f9c34fc3b069
```

Can someone help please? Thank you

Comment: That looks more like c than c++. In c++ we have [dynamic memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) and [container classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Comment: `a = (float **)malloc(m*sizeof(float));` You're using `sizeof(float)` when you should be using `sizeof(float*)`

Comment: Also you have a memory leak since `dezalocareM` is not deallocating the array of float pointers. And you're deallocating the wrong amount of float arrays in `dezalocareM` because you're looping up to `p` when you should be looping up to `m`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that your question has little to do with C++. It's completely C, as far as I can see. In C++, you would use `new` instead of `malloc` for the **rare** occasions in which you deal with low-level memory business, and classes like `std::string` or `std::vector` for higher levels.

Still, let's see what's wrong here.

The most apparent problem is that there is no connection between that which happens in `alocareV` and that which happens in `citireV`, same for `alocareM`/`citireM`. The result of your allocation functions **is discarded**. You must use the results:

```
v = alocareV(n);
a = alocareM(m, p);
```

There is also an error in `alocareM`. When you allocate memory for the double pointer, you should use `sizeof(float*)`, not `sizeof(float)`.

The next error is in `citireV`. `scanf_s` requires you to pass a pointer to the object to be written to. `*(v + i)`, however, yields a `float`, not a `float*`, because you dereference the pointer. The correct call would be:

```
scanf_s("%f", (v + i));
```

`citireM` has exactly the same error. The correct call should be:

```
scanf_s("%f", ( *(a + i) + j ) );
```

Finally, `main` must return `int`. `void main` is not legal in C or C++.

That should fix it.

Comment: _"In C++, you would use new"_ I strongly have to disagree. See my comment on the question what should be used in c++.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Smart pointers don't replace *all* uses for raw pointers. And they are implemented in terms of `new`, anyway. I consider them higher-level classes like `std::vector` or `std::string`. I think the most important thing for C++ beginners coming from Java or similar languages is to learn that they can create any object on the stack and don't even need dynamic memory allocation everywhere.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: And I was explicitly talking about "rare occasions" anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct code should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

float *alocareV(int n)
{
    float *v;
    v = (float *)malloc(n*sizeof(float));
    return v;
}

float **alocareM(int m, int p)
{
    float **a;
    int i;
    a = (float **)malloc(m*sizeof(float *));
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        *(a + i) = (float *)malloc(p*sizeof(float));
    return a;
}

void dezalocareM(float **a ,int p)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
        free (*(a + i));
}

void citireV(float *v, int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("v[%d]= ", i);
        scanf_s("%f", (v + i));
    }
}

void citireM(float **a, int m, int p)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m;i++)
    for (j = 0; j < p; j++)
    {
        printf("a[%d][%d]= ", i, j);
        scanf_s("%f", ( *(a + i) + j ) );
    }
}

void main()
{
    float *v=0, **a=0;
    int n, m, p;
    int i, j;

    printf("n este egal cu ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    printf("m este egal cu ");
    scanf_s("%d", &m);
    printf("p este egal cu ");
    scanf_s("%d", &p);

    v = alocareV(n);
    a = alocareM(m, p);

    citireV(v, n);
    citireM(a, m, p);

    free(v);
    dezalocareM(a, p);

}
```

change the

```
alocareV(n);
alocareM(m, p);
```

in main function to:

```
v = alocareV(n);
a = alocareM(m, p);
```

Also modified the scanf_s function arguments. Hope this will help you.

Comment: You should explain that a bit. Especially point out what you changed.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: His code is having mistake. I have just rectified it.

Comment: There's still a mistake in your version.

Comment: @zenith: What mistake?

Comment: `a = (float **)malloc(m*sizeof(float));` should use `sizeof(float*)`

Comment: Also there's still a memory leak. C.f. `dezalocareM` vs `alocareM`

Comment: @zenith: Yes and no. Strictly speaking, in this program, there is no memory leak because the program terminates immediately and the allocated memory is supposed to live as long as the program itself.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I am aware of that. I was just using the word to mean "failing to deallocate what was allocated".